ActivityFieldHistory: How the heck do we query it?

Edit: There have been a couple comments claiming this has already been addressed in other questions, which is not correct. Below is my explanation of why:
Dynamically Find if Object Support Batch
Addresses the fact that the ActivityFieldHistory table doesn't have any index fields and therefore cannot be access in Batch class... which is what I acknowledged in the very last sentence of my post.
Indexed Big Object SOQL limitation in Apex class
Explains the basics of Big Object queries, in particular that you cant use filters in WHERE clauses willy nilly, and have to include them all in order with limitations on operator types. As I state in my responding comment, that is what I attempted to do with my Third Query in my original post.

As the title says: How exactly are you supposed to use SOQL to check changes to field values on Tasks? You know, the same way we can with any custom object's history table?
As of Spring '23, we can now track specified fields' history on Tasks an Events. Great! We've been tracking the standard field CallDisposition aka Call Result. Goal: identify Task records where CallDisposition has changed non-null values in the past month.
ActivityFieldHistory and ActivityHistory are both documented objects: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_activityfieldhistory.htm
ActivityFieldHistory seems like the way to go, but I am finding it severely restricted for use in SOQL queries.
First Query
SELECT ActivityId, ChangedDate, oldvaluetext, newvaluetext 
FROM ActivityFieldHistory 
WHERE ChangedDate >= 2024-10-16T00:00:00Z
      AND FieldName = 'CallDisposition' 

gives this error

I can find no info on what is considered a 'range filter'. I know it has something to do with Big Object usage, since History tables are Big Objects. However, changing the order of the WHERE parameters doesn't change the error.
Second Query
SELECT ActivityId, ChangedDate, oldvaluetext, newvaluetext 
FROM ActivityFieldHistory 
WHERE FieldName = 'CallDisposition'

Omitting one of the filters gives me this error:

My understanding of this error is that all the filters stated on the ActivityFieldHistory documentation need to be used in the WHERE clause, in order. So ActivityId,  ChangedById, etc, all need to be included in order in the WHERE clause. Not sure if that's correct but that's what I tried...
Third Query
SELECT ActivityId, ChangedDate, oldvaluetext, newvaluetext 
FROM ActivityFieldHistory 
WHERE ActivityId != null AND
      ChangedById != null AND
      ChangedDate != null AND
      FieldName = 'CallDisposition'

I went through the field list on the object and every field with a property of 'filter' I included in the WHERE clause... but I still get the same error: Filters may not have any gaps within the composite key
Final Query
SELECT ActivityId, ChangedDate, oldvaluetext, newvaluetext 
FROM ActivityFieldHistory 

Ok fine, I'd be willing to do the work myself in Excel or whatever, and filter for dates and fieldname, and do the VLOOKUP to tie to Task field info... but the results from this straightforward query are... strange:

Early queries of this type returned literally a single record (that changed on each rerun of the query). Now I'm getting more than one result, but certainly not a complete set of results... and I'm surprised to not be hitting SOQL limit errors given that there should be way more ActivityHistory records than SOQL can handle.
I also understand from another post that this object can't be access via batch class or alternative batch processes.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/423605/dynamically-find-if-object-support-batch/423608#423608 https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/248375/indexed-big-object-soql-limitation-in-apex-class

This question is similar to: Indexed Big Object SOQL limitation in Apex class. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Unfortunately I had already reviewed all 3 of the links the two of your comments provide before posting, and address all the scenarios they address in my post above, and why it doesn't work. For example, @PhilW, your link describes needing to list index filters in order, using only = operators except for the last one, which is precisely what I do in the Third Query in my post. Part of the issue is that SF documentation doesn't explain what makes up the 'composite key' of this big object.

Also this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/327759/filters-may-not-have-any-gaps-within-the-composite-key-querying-fieldhistoryarch

Thanks you're right, doesn't resolve the errors though

Sorry, I deleted my comment without seeing your comment. Correct is to use a WHERE for 'Task.CallDisposition'.

I assume ActivityFieldHistory is a Big Object. In order to resolve the problem in the WHERE, let's first find the correct order of the available fields for the WHERE. (For this limitation of Big Objects see here.) Which order works? Look for "Properties: Filter..." in each individual field of the Object Reference. The following is an example that worked for me, based on the 4 found fields, with the correct order in the WHERE.
SELECT Id, ChangedById  
FROM ActivityFieldHistory
WHERE ActivityId IN('00TG5000006fWBmMAM', '00TG5000006fb4zMAA') 
AND ChangedDate = 2025-01-01T00:00:00Z
AND ChangedById = '005G500000CGSSvIAP'
AND FieldName = 'Task.CallDisposition'

Remarks:

Big Objects don't support "!=" in the WHERE clause. Comparisons like "!= NULL" are therefore futile.

The correct reference to the field is 'Task.CallDisposition'.


Given the prescribed adverse order of the fields in the WHERE, we probably should limit the WHERE to the minimum. With the following I was able to get a reasonable result:
List<Task> tasks = [SELECT Id FROM Task];
// Obviously we will want to check several Tasks in one go, depending
// on how many field changes there are. Apologies for the SOQL in a
// loop - there is hardly a nice way doing this.
for(Task t : tasks) {
    Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>{t.Id};
    List<ActivityFieldHistory> l = [
        SELECT 
            ActivityId, ChangedDate, FieldName, 
            OldValueText, NewValueText, 
            OldValueNumber, NewValueNumber,
            OldValueDateTime, NewValueDateTime
        FROM ActivityFieldHistory
        WHERE ActivityId IN: ids
    ];
    System.debug(l);
}

As for why you don't see any old and new text values of fields: You don't SELECT for the FieldName. Are the shown fields possibly number or date fields?
